# Django filtering based on list value

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-rest-framework

My JSON data is in this format..

```
[
    {
        "id": "532befe4ee434047ff968a6e",
        "company": "528458c4bbe7823947b6d2a3",
        "values" : [
                        {
                             "Value":"11",
                             "uniqueId":true
                        },
                        {
                             "Value":"14",
                             "uniqueId":true
                        },
                     ]
     },
     {
        "id": "532befe4ee434047ff968a",
        "company": "528458c4bbe7823947b6d",
        "values" : [
                        {
                             "Value":"1111",
                             "uniqueId":true
                        },
                        {
                             "Value":"10",
                             "uniqueId":true
                        },
                     ]
     }

]
```

If I want to filter based on company field then it is possible in this way.

```
qaresults = QAResult.objects.filter(company= comapnyId)
```

and it gives me first dictionary of list

But what If I want to filter this based on values list's "value" of Value Key of first dictionary ?

Comment: Its not valid json . validate here : http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Your `values` is a string, not a list.

Comment: Ya , it may not be , but how to filter based on values of list of dictionary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not 100% sure what you want , but from what i understand your question,
Try this solution :

```
import json
json_dict = json.loads('[{"id": "532befe4ee434047ff968a6e","company": "528458c4bbe7823947b6d2a3","values": [{"Value": "11","uniqueId": true},{"Value": "14","uniqueId": true}]},{"id": "532befe4ee434047ff968a","company": "528458c4bbe7823947b6d","values": [{"Value": "1111","uniqueId": true},{"Value": "10","uniqueId": true}]}]')

expected_values = []

js = json_dict[0]
for key,value in js.items():
    if key == 'values':
        expected_values.append(value[0]['Value'])
```

And then

```
qaresults = QAResult.objects.filter(company__id__in = expected_values)
```